# XML using Javascript in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome

Hy all,

I am using a code that goes through an XML file and show me the data..
That code works great in IE, Firefox and Opera..
Now I would like to know how to configure it to work on Chrome..

Using the `navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"` and `navigator.appName == "Netscape"`, I was capable of testing the identity of the browser used, and whether to use ActiveX objects or httpRequest.

Keeping in mind, when alerting the `navigator.appName` , on Chrome, Firefox and Opera, I get Netscape.

This is the full version of my code:

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    alert(navigator.appName);
    if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        xhttp.open("GET", "http://www.multimediaprof.com/test/emp2.xml", false);
    }
    else if (navigator.appName == "Netscape") {

        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        alert("step 1");

        xhttp.open("GET", "emp2.xml", false);
    }
    alert("step 2");
    xhttp.send("");
    alert("step 3");
    xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;
    alert("step 4");
    alert(xmlDoc);
    document.write(xmlDoc.documentElement.nodeName + " loaded");
    alert("step 5");
    var str = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("to")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    alert("step 6");
    alert(str);​

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

New full version of code suggested now :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var xhttp, xmlDoc, str;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "emp2.xml", false);
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
  xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   xhttp.open("GET", "http://www.multimediaprof.com/test/emp2.xml", false);
} else {
  alert("Cannot create XmlHttpRequest object");
}
if (xhttp) {
  xhttp.send("");

  if (xhttp.responseXML != null) {
    xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;
    str = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("to")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    alert(str);
  } else {
    alert("Server response was invalid.");
  }
}
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use `appName` at all.

```
var xhttp, xmlDoc, str;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
  xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
} else {
  alert("Cannot create XmlHttpRequest object");
}
if (xhttp) {
  xhttp.open("GET", "emp2.xml", false);
  xhttp.send();

  if (xhttp.responseXML != null) {
    xmlDoc = responseXML;
    str = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("to")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    alert(str);
  } else {
    alert("Server response was invalid.");
  }
}
```

Note:

- You *must* declare all the variables you use. There is no reason ever not to declare a variable.
- You really should use asynchronous requests. Learn how to use them. Synchronous requests are bad and wrong.
- You should never ever use `document.write()`.
- You should always check things before you use them. For example, you cannot simply use `xhttp.responseXML` without even checking that it exists.
  The same goes for `getElementsByTagName("to")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue`. This can fail at any time. If you never expect an error here, at least wrap it in a try/catch block and handle unexpected errors gracefully.
- There is `console.log()`. That's a lot better than `alert()`.

Comment: Your code only worked on firefox and IE....and to make it work on them it needed tweeking

Comment: I still don't have access in google chrome...any ideas ? is there something special to announce or stuff?

Comment: The above works for me in Google Chrome, no change or tweaking required. You are doing something else wrong.

Comment: In chrome i get : Uncaught Error : NETWORL_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101 right under the xhttp.send("");

Comment: I solved the problem and it runs smoothly on firefox, opera and IE but still that same error on chrome, and that error i already had it with my own basic code...so that's no new error! please help anyone

Comment: Have you tried googling the error? You seem to be trying to load local files (`file://`) or files from a different server. This does not work. And it has nothing to do with the code above. *(PS: Please don't use comments as an interactive debugging session.)*